# Как убрать Warning и Notises, когда я ввожу неправильный пароль или электронную почту в форме входа через imap_open?

Tags: php, imap

Как убрать Warning и Notises, когда я ввожу неправильный пароль или электронную почту в форме входа через imap_open? И как сделать проверку, если пароль или почта была введена не верно? Я не использую MySQL, а передаю пароль и логин напрямую в imap_open.
Вот ошибки:

> Warning: 'imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX' and
>
> Notice: Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Client aborted AUTHENTICATE command. i145-v6mb122753825lfi (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: IMAP Authentication cancelled (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Мне нужна проверка, когда я ввожу неправильный пароль и электронную почту, что бы выводило "Не правильный пароль или почта" и возвращало форму входу в почту. Я пытался сделать проверку, но нотайсы всеравно выводятся. Пожалуйста, подскажите мне, что я делаю неправильно.

function imap_open:

```
function open_mailbox($auth_user, $auth_password) {
    $mailbox = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    if($imap = imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password)){
        imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        imap_close($imap);
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

function of login form

```
function display_login_form($action) { ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=log-in">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>LOGIN</p>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>MAIL</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>PASSWORD</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div>
                    <input type='submit' value='LOGIN'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

index.php

```
$username = "";
$password = "";
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
}
if(null!==($username && $password)) {
    if(open_mailbox($username, $password)) {
        $action = 'view-mailbox';
        $_SESSION['auth_user'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['auth_password'] = $password;
    } else {
        $status .= "<p>Wrong password or email</p>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Не подскажете в чём прикол дважды открывать imap и закрывать, когда он не открыт?